# Hyundai i10 2013 Manual Gear Problem

Tags: transmission, hyundai

My car has 78 000 miles on the clock. Recently, when I've been driving in 5th at 60-70mph the tachometer jumps up 500-1000rpm and the light to move up to 5th gear shows up on the dashboard.

There's no loss of power. The gear stick itself hasn't moved. It usually takes a couple of attempts of putting it into neutral and then moving back up to 5th for the tachometer to return to it's normal levels and for the dashboard light to turn off. No other problems with the car itself.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be? Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe a slipping clutch. It may be time for a new clutch assembly.

Comment: sounds like slipping but you would probably be able to notice it at lower speeds too. Expect $300 DIY or $1k+ for shop if that is the problem. Good luck  
edit: I don't know anything about Hyundai, I'm assuming $150 for clutch kit, $50-$75 for flywheel resurface and new bolts etc